# C: How to add a try again function to this asterisk square printing program

Tags: c

I need a program that asks for an integer &prints out an emtpy asterisk square based on the input number. And if the input was invalid then i need it to try and ask again
.
THIS is what i have so far (it already can make a square based on a variable number) i just need to enhence it so it asks again if the user is too dumb to input an integer

```
#include <stdio.h>
int Loops() {
    int s, e, z; 
    printf("Input number \n");
    scanf("%d", &s);
    for(e = 0; e < s; e++) {
        for(z = 0; z < s; z++) {   
            if(e==0 || e==s-1 || z==0 || z==s-1)
                printf("*");
            else
                printf(" ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int main() { 
   Loops();
}
```

i think the teacher mentioned something of adding a switch case...?

Comment: Loops generally helps for doing something again. And if you want to validate the input you read with [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf), then it helps knowing what [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) might return. And knowing that if [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) fails, that it will leave the input in the input buffer.

Comment: so what i am to do

Comment: Is this a homework than? We usually don't really like to answer homeworks here unless maybe you have a very specific coding problem giving at least an attempt to solve your problem. Until now I see no attempt to solve anything using a `switch-case` or `if` or even cheking `s` for anything...

Answer (score 1):

I propose this solution, in a few words I check the type of number entered by the user, if it's >0 then run,you do not have to worry that it is float because you have defined an integer type and the part not integer is automatically troncated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int Loops() {
    int s, e, z;
    printf("Input number \n");
    scanf("%d", &s);
    if (s > 0 ) {
        for (e = 0; e < s; e++) {
            for (z = 0; z < s; z++) {
                if(e == 0 || e == s - 1 || z == 0 || z == s - 1)
                    printf("*");
                else
                    printf(" ");
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    } 
    else
        Loops();
}

int main() {
   Loops();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: If a user entered `A` or `B` or any other alphabet? Then?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use an infinite loop i.e. `while(1)` loop with a condition to `break`. Let's say you want a user to input positive integer and discard negative numbers and alphabets as well, you can do that in the following manner:

```
int Loops() {
int s, e, z;

while(1)
{
    printf("Input number \n");
    e = scanf("%d", &s);
    if((s <= 0) || (e != 1))
    {
        printf("Please Enter Non-negaitve Number\n");
        getchar(); //This is to consume the '\n'
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}

for(e = 0; e < s; e++) {
    for(z = 0; z < s; z++) {
        if(e==0 || e==s-1 || z==0 || z==s-1)
            printf("*");
        else
            printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}
```